"Seeking Assistance with Zoom Feature for 3D Planet Models"
"How can I implement zoom functionality to focus on a specific 3D model, such as a planet, when it's clicked by the user? I'm using the Three.js library to render multiple 3D models."
I attempted to utilize RayCasting to detect the clicked model, but unfortunately, it didn't yield the desired outcome.
Here is JavaScript Code
import TrackballControls from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three-trackballcontrols@0.9/index.min.js'
// Create a scene


var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var planetPositions = [];

// Load the sun model
var sunLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
sunLoader.load('./models/sun.glb', function (gltf) {
    var sun = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(sun);
});


// Load planet models
var planets = [];
var planetNames = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune'];
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
let distanceFactor = 50;
planetNames.forEach(function (name, index) {
    loader.load('models/'+name + '.glb', function (gltf) {
        var planet = gltf.scene;
        planets.push(planet);
        planet.scale.set(2,2,2)
        scene.add(planet);
        let ran = Math.random();
        if (ran > 0.5) {
            planet.position.set((index + 1) * distanceFactor, (index + 1) * distanceFactor, ((index + 1) * distanceFactor));
        } else {
            distanceFactor = -50;
            planet.position.set(((index + 1) * distanceFactor), ((index + 1) * distanceFactor), ((index + 1) * distanceFactor));
        }
        
    });
});

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directionalLight.position.set(50, 0, 0).normalize(); // Set light position
scene.add(directionalLight);
var directionalLightt = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directionalLightt.position.set(-50, 0, 0).normalize(); // Set light position
scene.add(directionalLightt);
var directionalLighttt = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directionalLighttt.position.set(0, -50, 0).normalize(); // Set light position
scene.add(directionalLighttt);
var directionalLightttt = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directionalLightttt.position.set(0, 50, 0).normalize(); // Set light position
scene.add(directionalLightttt);

// Add light to the scene
var sunLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1); // Creating a point light with white color
sunLight.position.set(0, 0, 0); // Positioning the light at the center of the scene (where the sun is)
scene.add(sunLight);

// Set up camera, renderer, and controls
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(50, 0, 0); 
scene.add(camera);
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.5;
controls.enableZoom = false;

const controls2 = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls2.noRotate = true;
controls.noPan = true;
controls2.noZoom = false;
controls2.zoomSpeed = 1.5;

// Load the panoramic image
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load('models/panorami.jpg');

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5000, 60, 40); // Adjust the radius as needed

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.BackSide });

var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(skybox);

function animate() {
    const target = controls.target
    controls.update()
    controls2.target.set(target.x,target.y,target.z);
    controls2.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();


Also Here's HTML File
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D Solar System</title>
    
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 120vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three-trackballcontrols@0.9.0/index.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r92/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>


"It didn't yield the desired outcome" - Please add more details to the question. What does this mean? What is the desired outcome?
